# How to make permanent url to file in svn?

Tags: url, svn, hyperlink, tortoisesvn

Good day, colleagues,

can you advice me, how to make permanent links to files in SVN?

If I make a link, now I get something like:

http://172.29.15.15/svn/OFFICE_WORK/Trainings/123.xlsx

but if I move file to other directory, I get a error (file not found).

I know that in Sharepoint I can assign unique IDs (aditional option in admin panel) to files, and I'll get a permanent URL to file, that doesn't depend on it's location.

Is there an opportunity in SVN to make permanent link to file, that not depend on it's location?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly when you say "permanent link". But try adding an external property to your checked out directory. Right click on the directory you wish to add the 123.xslx file to, go to TortoiseSVN > Properties > New > Externals.

Then click **New...**, give the local path to the file and URL to the file which you posted above
Example:
Local Path: 123.xlsx
URL: http://172.29.15.15/svn/OFFICE_WORK/Trainings/123.xlsx

Hit OK. OK, again. Then do an SVN Update on the folder. Your 123.xlsx file should be included.

Not sure what you're referring to by not depending on location though. In subversion, in order to pull a file, you have to have the URL to gather it from. There isn't any ID feature unfortunately. It seems your repositories are based off an IP address of some sort... Is there any way you can use a common domain name for your path? That would probably solve your issue as well.